# File format for submitting iPhone app in App Store

Tags: ios4, app-store

When I am building my app,Xcode generates it in .app format. Usually when I install app from AppStore they are in .ipa format. How does this format get generated? Will it be done by guys at AppStore while reviewing app or what? In which format should I compress my .app file?

Thanks

Comment: you dont have to compress in any format to give it to appstore.And only people form appstore(apple) can convert it to .ipa format and thats the reason why are they only one to sell the apps for iphone

Comment: so by default Xcode makes AppName.app file. I just compress it and upload on portal?

Comment: @robin - Actually, you do have to compress your application bundle before submission.  Also, there's nothing special about an .ipa file, it's just a zipped-up application bundle.

Answer (score 1):

An .ipa file is simply a zipped archive of a .app bundle.  Previously, you would simply zip up the compiled application bundle (by right-clicking on it and choosing `Compress "xxx.app"`) before submission, but newer versions of Xcode now do this for you with their `Build and Archive` or `Archive` options.

In fact, you might be able to learn things by unzipping other application .ipa files you get via the App Store and inspecting their contents (like Info.plist settings or bundled resources).  I know I have.